# Can printf() be made SMP safe?

Tags: termios, smp, rtems

I'm trying to get RTEMS running using SMP on a Leon3/gr712rc (2 cores). I have it partially running, but it crashes intermittently on printf's.  Can anyone tell me if there's a way to make printf() SMP safe?  printf appears to use termios which uses rtems_mutex_init() and rtems_binary_semaphore_init() which I don't think are SMP safe (but I'm also new to this so I'm not sure).
Thanks!